# Perpendicular mapping from one matrix group to a closed matrix subgroup

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let H be a connected closed Lie subgroup of G, which is a connected closed Lie subgroup of GL(n,), where  = ℝ or  = ℂ. Assume that G and H are each endowed with the riemannian metric inherited from GL(n,) that GL(n,) obtains as a smooth submanifold of ℝ<sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup>.

Alternatively this could be considered with all distances measured across ℝ<sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup>.

Does there exist a standard method — ideally a formula — for determining an explicit map G → H taking each g ∈ G' to the nearest point of H (when a unique nearest point exists)? Here G' denotes the subset of G having a unique nearest point of H.

One idea might be to find a logarithm log(g) of g in the Lie algebra Lie(G) of G and project it perpendicularly to the Lie algebra of H sitting within it, using the intrinsic inner product, and then apply exp to the resulting element of Lie(H). I am not sure if this will give the desired result.

In case H = SO(n) if  = ℝ (or H = U(n) if  = ℂ), is the orthogonal (or unitary) matrix that occurs in the polar decomposition of g ∈ G necessarily going to be the nearest point of H ?

In general the cases of greatest interest are when H is the compact subgroup of G onto which G deformation retracts.